# Run commands "without" terminal

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, lxde

Months ago I saw a guy running commands from a small, text-box-like window, showing nothing else other than the text-box for you to write the command. Such text-box would popup by pressing some keyboard shortcut. Specifically, from what I remember, he was using Lubuntu, and mostly opening apps (like Chrome, Audacious, etc.).

I've never found anything like it, and I've searched considerably for it.

Is it a known extension for lxde or did he most probably create it by himself?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: what about alt+f2?

Comment: nothing happened :/

Comment: Also asked at http://askubuntu.com/questions/625440/ .

Comment: Cross posting is not allowed on U&L, and chit-chat like "Thanks everyone" is inappropriate according to the help->tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

I'm not totally sure about this though, as when I search `Alt+F2 in LXDE` on Google there seem to be a fair number of results about a bug. Not sure if those still apply.

However, this is the shortcut that worked for me last time I used LXDE.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happened. Thx anyway!

Comment: Well, it was exactly what i was looking for, but i had to fix it using the instructons here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217758. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @LucasF No problem! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

While Ubuntu's default <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> is pretty useful, I've noticed in the comments that it does not work for you. An alternative run dialog that you can use is `bbrun`.  This run dialog is originally for `black box` desktop environment, but can still be used elsewhere. Install it using `sudo apt-get install bbrun`. Once you do, run it in terminal with `nohup bbrun &` and you should have a star-like icon appear on your desktop. It's pretty small, so you might wanna look around the edges of your screen.

[image]

Clicking on that star icon brings up the run dialog

Alternativelly, you could bind a shortcut to the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
COMMAND=$( zenity --entry --text="What to run?" )

/bin/sh -c "$COMMAND" &
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. But I could indeed make Alt+F2 work! I'll put the link as a comment in my question.

Comment: @Serg One of your images is not quite there....

Comment: @somethingSomething yeah, I tried it twice - didn't load. I'll just get rid of it